# Большое время ответа сервера при загрузке страницы сайта на WordPress

Tags: wordpress, оптимизация-сайтов

С чем может быть связано то, что сервер тупит 2 секунды?

Гугл говорит это:

"Сократите время ответа сервера"
По результатам тестирования время ответа вашего сервера составило 2,1 секунды. На этот показатель влияет много факторов. Ознакомьтесь с нашими рекомендациями и узнайте, как можно отслеживать и измерять время ответа.

Вот инспектировал загрузку страницы в браузере:

[image: Скрин]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тормозня происходит по следующим причинам.

1. Ваш сервер у чёрта на рогах (в США), до него даже ping ходит 150 мс.
2. Вы используете виртуальный хостинг GoDaddy (да ещё, вероятно, дешёвенькие тарифы), на котором жуткий оверселлинг и вечная тормозня из-за перегрузки серваков.

Хотите быстрой отдачи - купите как минимум VDS у нормального хостера и поближе к целевой аудитории.

Comment: Целевая аудитория находится в США.
Наверное всё таки дело в хостинге.
Спасибо

Comment: Для проверки можно взять VDS на бесплатный тест и проверить. Многие дают. Я сталкивался с GoDaddy, iPage и им подобными - ужасные тормоза.

Comment: Попробовал открыть файл html с текстом, открылся мгновенно и таких тормозов нет. Видимо дело таки в вордпресе. Не подскажешь в какую сторону копать?

Comment: HTML с текстом не требует обработки и просто отдаётся сервером в неизменном виде. Wordpress - это набор PHP-кода, причём немалого объёма, для обработки которого нужно много ресурсов процессора. Кроме того, нужны обращения к БД, которая может тормозить и сама по себе.

Comment: Можно попробовать поставить "пустой" Wordpress и проверить. Если и на нём тормоза, то виноват, скорее всего, хостер. Если "пустой" работает быстро, то тормозит настроенный Wordpress. Для чистоты эксперимента можно поставить Joomla!, чтобы полностью исключить влияние Wordpress.